# How to create a menu item as an addon that is displayed in the left side pane

Tags: python, add-on

I want to create a menu item in the left side pane with a text box and file browser included in it. I know how to create a simple addon. But couldnt understand how to create a menu item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Text Editor then choose Templates->Python you will find templates for simple menus and panels (`Ui Menu`, `Ui Simple Menu`, `Ui Panel`, `Ui Simple Panel`), run them and see how it goes, they should give you a very good understanding of what you can do.

[image]

Running the UI Simple Panel will show it under the object properties as shown below, the location of the panel is specified using these three class parameters:

```
bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
bl_context = "object"
```

[image]

To put in the left side you change the values as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When running that where will it show up? I was trying to run Ui Panel Simple. But couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: @user5507 answer updated showing where it is located

Comment: How to do that in the left side panel?

Comment: @user5507 answer updated to put it on the left side. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.